# get current user in grails spock unit testing which uses spring security

Tags: spring-security, grails-plugin, spock

```
package com.rohan

import grails.test.mixin.*
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService
import grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin
import com.rohan.meta.MetaServiceCategory

@TestFor(ProjectDashBoardController)
            @Mock([SpringSecurityService,User,Project,MetaServiceCategory,ProjectIntroduction,ProjectDetails,ProjectAdditionalInfo,SPCompany,BuyerCompany,Conversation,ServiceCategory,UserAuthService,TimeSheetService,ProjectService])
class ProjectDashBoardControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test timeSheets action"() {

        given:
        BuyerCompany buyerCompany = new BuyerCompany()
        Project testProject = new Project(title: "test    Project",projectId:"0411",buyerCompany:buyerCompany)
        testProject.save()
        println "project : "+testProject

        when:"When Project Id Given"
        controller.params.id = "00411"
        controller.timeSheets()

        then:
        response.redirectUrl.endsWith '/dashboard/index'
    }
}
```

Here is controller code:

```
class ProjectDashBoardController {

    def springSecurityService
    def userAuthService

    def timeSheets(){
        def project=Project.findByProjectId(params.id)
        if(project){
            def user = userAuthService.getCurrentUser()
            // Do Something
        } else {
            redirect(controller:'dashboard',action:'index')
        }
     }
}
```

@OPAL
i think that's what u asking

class UserAuthService {

def getCurrentUser(){
        def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
        return user
    }
}
And finally I receive the following error:

```
Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object
    at com.rohan.UserAuthService.getCurrentUser(UserAuthService.groovy:22)
    at com.rohan.ProjectDashBoardController.timeSheets(ProjectDashBoardController.groovy:130)
    at com.rohan.ProjectDashBoardControllerSpec.test timeSheets action(ProjectDashBoardControllerSpec.groovy:29)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see validated answer, maybe it will help somebody else :

With grails, if you want userAuthService or other services (like grails core services or your own) you have several possibilities like :

1. Stub/Mock them in a unit test and define the behaviour
2. Make your unit test an integration test

**1. Stub/Mock them in a unit test**

Here with a Stub :

```
void "test timeSheets action"() {
    given:
    ...your code...
    def userAuthService = Stub(UserAuthService)
    User currUser = new User(email: "current@current.fr", firstname: "firstname")
    // Here we define the behaviour of our Stubbed service :
    userAuthService.getCurrentUser() >> currUser

    and:"we inject our fake userAuthService"
    controller.userAuthService = userAuthService

    when:"When Project Id Given"
    ...your code...

    then:
    ...your code...
}
```

NOTE : you can use Mock(UserAuthService) in place of Stub(UserAuthService). Then you'll be able to verify in the "then" part that getCurrentUser() has been called once with

```
1 * userAuthService.getCurrentUser()
```

**2. Make your unit test an integration test**

From grails documentation about Testing

> Integration tests differ from unit tests in that you have full access
>   to the Grails environment within the test. Grails uses an in-memory H2
>   database for integration tests and clears out all the data from the
>   database between tests.

Answer (score 0):

You declare `userAuthService` but I can't see any place it's injected or initialized.

Comment: injected..??..can u please explain how i do that...it'll be very helpful

Comment: No idea how. I'm not a grails developer. Just see that it causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a unit test (not integration one) you should just create `Mock` or `Stub` of your `userAuthService` and inject it into the controller. By inject in this specific case just use setter like `controller.userAuthService = serviceStub`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void "test timeSheets action"() {
    setup:
    testUser = new User()
    controller.userAuthService = [currentUser: testUser]


    given:
    BuyerCompany buyerCompany = new BuyerCompany()
    Project testProject = new Project(title: "test    Project",projectId:"0411",buyerCompany:buyerCompany)
    testProject.save()
    println "project : "+testProject

    when:"When Project Id Given"
    controller.params.id = "00411"
    controller.timeSheets()

    then:
    response.redirectUrl.endsWith '/dashboard/index'
}
```

As part of setup section of your test, Mock Test User and inject to userAuthServices. I had similar problem and it did the fix.