# Grails Unit Test Case doesn't initialize Grails Service

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea

Grails Unit Test Case doesn't initialize my Grails Service.

```
public class ProfileDataServiceTests extends GrailsUnitTestCase{

    ProfileDataService profileDataService;
    void testprocessRawData() {
        profileDataService.processRawData(getCustomerData())
    }

}
```

Intellij Idea shows profileDataService is auto wired, when i invoke a method on it, i get NullPointerException as profileDataService is null.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: which grails version you are using?

Comment: Grails Version 2.2.4

Comment: I've made an answer here that maybe can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277504/get-current-user-in-grails-spock-unit-testing-which-uses-spring-security/36846469#36846469

Answer (score 0):

If you see this tutorial you will see grailsUnitTestCase are deprecated since grails 2.0.x

> Grails 1.3.x and below used the grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase class
>   hierarchy for testing in a JUnit 3 style. Grails 2.0.x and above
>   deprecates these test harnesses in favour of mixins that can be
>   applied to a range of different kinds of tests (JUnit 3, JUnit 4,
>   Spock etc.) without subclassing

So you can use this link which provides better way of grails unit testing.

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/testing.html#unitTestingControllers

kind of this way

```
@Integration
class NameSpec extends Specification {

  @Autowired
  ExampleService exampleService
}
```

Hope this helps! Thanks

Comment: When I try your example with my Service, it complains saying No Nean Definition with Service Name and hence unable to auto wire the Service.

I am using Grails Version 2.2.4.